# websockets - server side visualization

Tags: node.js, websocket, processing

I'm using websockets (node.js with ws.js) to receive realtime messages from online clients. How can I access these incoming messages on my visualization sketch (processing or processing.js) that runs on my server side?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean here - Processing can run anywhere, as a standalone application (compiled as java), Processing.js is what you use if you want to run a sketch on the web (compiled as JavaScript). If you want to know how to hook up a sketch with 'the rest of the page' for generate JavaScript work, have a look at http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html, but if that's not what you meant, please clarify your question =)

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make myself a bit more clear: I would like to project an interactive game scenario on some big screen/wall. The players controls/participate in the game using their mobile phones (in html5 using websockets) and the visualization runs only on the server side.

Comment: better to add that as update text to your main post, so that people don't have to look through a comment thread for it. If you're using Node and socket.io or something, you can simply make node pump the data to the client page, and have the page JS tell your sketch what to do by following the JS->sketch interfacing explained in the guide.